# ASP.NET GridView lost jquery datatable formatting after a async post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I have a asp.net GridView converted to jquery datatable when I click a button inside the GridView a lost the datatable formatting and throw an error in the console

This is the GridView in the source :

```xml
<!-- GridView -->
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlGrid" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvMovies" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-bordered myTable" EmptyDataText="No data found !"
                OnRowCommand="gvMovies_RowCommand" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gvMovies_PageIndexChanging"
                OnRowDataBound="gvMovies_RowDataBound">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead-dark text-center" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Référence" HeaderStyle-CssClass="d-none" ItemStyle-CssClass="d-none" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Genre" HeaderText="Genre" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Rate" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <!-- View button with icon -->
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnView" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-view"
                                CommandName="btnView"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>
                                <i class="bi bi-eye-fill text-white"></i>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            <!-- Edit button with icon -->
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" CommandName="btnEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>
                                <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill text-white"></i>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            <!-- Delete button with icon -->
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" CommandName="btnDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>
                                <i class="bi bi-trash-fill text-white"></i>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after binding your gridview and on every postback event.

```
if (gvMovies.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    gvMovies.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    gvMovies.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Not working bro still lose the jquery datatable formatting.

Comment: @Abderrahim can you tell exactly what error you are getting ?

Comment: I don't get any error in the console but when I click a link button inside a GridView a lost jquery datatable formatting because the page is reload and clear all javascript code

Comment: Try calling that javascript after the postback, maybe that would work.